# Django EmailField accepts invalid values

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm currently using the default `EmailField` attribute on my form. The issue I'm running into is that the form considers an invalid email such as `name@mail.56` to be valid. Do I need to implement my own `validators` on this field to make it work correctly?

I was under the impression that having:

```
#models.py
email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, blank=False, unique=True,
        error_messages={'required': 'Please provide your email address.',
                        'unique': 'An account with this email exist.'},)
```

Or having:

```
#forms.py
email = forms.EmailField()
```

will take care of this type of validation for me but it doesn't seem so.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Indeed, `name@mail.56` email is a valid email for django `EmailValidator`, see no errors:

```
>>> from django.core.validators import validate_email
>>> validate_email("name@mail.56")
>>>
```

Django (1.5.1) uses the following regular expression for validating email address:

```
r"(^[-!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{}|~0-9A-Z]+(\.[-!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{}|~0-9A-Z]+)*"  # dot-atom
    # quoted-string, see also https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.2.5
    r'|^"([\001-\010\013\014\016-\037!#-\[\]-\177]|\\[\001-\011\013\014\016-\177])*"'
    r')@((?:[A-Z0-9](?:[A-Z0-9-]{0,61}[A-Z0-9])?\.)+(?:[A-Z]{2,6}\.?|[A-Z0-9-]{2,}\.?)$)'  # domain
    r'|\[(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)){3}\]$'
```

And it actually follows [RFC2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822) standard.

If you want to make `name@mail.56` fail during validation, you can create your own validator, and add it to `EmailField` validators with built-in `validate_email` validator, like this:

```
from django.core.validators import validate_email
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

def custom_validate_email(value):
    if <custom_check>:
        raise ValidationError('Email format is incorrect')
...
email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, blank=False, unique=True, validators=[validate_email, custom_validate_email)
```

And, FYI, you can always file a ticket in [django ticket system](https://code.djangoproject.com/) or ask about the issue on django IRC channel (irc://irc.freenode.net/django).

See also: [Writing validators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/validators/#writing-validators).

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 7):

You can see the used regex [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.5.1/django/core/validators.py#L81).

I think it doesn't discard 100% of the wrong emails. That's why in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#emailfield) it says:

> Validates that the given value is a valid email address, using a
>   moderately complex regular expression.

What I understand from this is that it doesn't do a perfect validation due to a design decision (it would be a performance trade-off).

Finally, I'm pretty sure that your example `name@mail.56` **is a valid email**. The domain part of an email address can be an IP (both IPv4 and IPv6) or a hostname. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname#Restrictions_on_valid_host_names) for further info in the subject.

Answer (score 2):

For DB level only validation you will have to call `full_clean` manually.

Three important citations from documentation:

[How validators are run](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/validators/#how-validators-are-run)

> See the form validation for more information on how validators are run
>   in forms, and Validating objects for how they’re run in models. Note
>   that validators will not be run automatically when you save a model,
>   but if you are using a ModelForm, it will run your validators on any
>   fields that are included in your form. See the ModelForm documentation
>   for information on how model validation interacts with forms.

[Model.clean_fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean_fields)

> The second step full_clean() performs is to call Model.clean(). This
>   method should be overridden to perform custom validation on your
>   model.

[Model.full_clean](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.full_clean)

> Note that full_clean() will not be called automatically when you call
>   your model’s save() method. You’ll need to call it manually when you
>   want to run one-step model validation for your own manually created
>   models.

```
from django.db import models


class MyTable(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().full_clean()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```